# i have 2 textures, how can i turn one the textures on and off?

Tags: materials, node-editor

[image]

I have a snow image texture, and a dirt image texture. how can i set it up so I can control how much of the snow texture is showing? for example if i set a value to 0, no snow will be showing on the dirt. if i set it to 1, snow is all over.

Comment: You've almost done it. What are you missing here exactly?

Comment: i'm not sure but i think i'm missing something. i want to be able to turn the snow off and on but i'm not sure what to use for that.

Comment: you mean a straight cut? if yes either make the two stops of the color ramp very close to each other or replace the color ramp by a math node with a less than

Comment: ColorRamp node between MixRGB and Principled BSDF?

Answer (score 2):

One simple method is to add a Maths 'Add' node between your texture and the color ramp. This allows you in set an offset to the texture to raise or lower it so it's more towards one texture or the other - ie, negative values will be more one texture, 0.0 will be an even mix, positive values will be more of the other texture (with larger values pushing the mix more in that direction).

[image: example maths node]

Answer (score 0):

You could simply connect to your single texture node to the principle BSDF Base node. or can try color ramp very close to each other with minimum of texture you don't want or maximum of texture you want to look.